# awk remove unwanted records and consolidate multiline fields to one line record in specific order

Tags: replace, awk, ldap, getline

I have an output file that I am trying to process into a formatted csv for our audit team.

I thought I had this mastered until I stumbled across bad data within the output. As such, I want to be able to handle this using awk.

**MY OUTPUT FILE EXAMPLE**

```
Enter password ==>
o=hoster

ou=people,o=hoster

ou=components,o=hoster

ou=websphere,ou=components,o=hoster

cn=joe-bloggs,ou=appserver,ou=components,o=hoster
cn=joe
sn=bloggs
cn=S01234565
uid=bloggsj

cn=john-blain,ou=appserver,ou=components,o=hoster
cn=john
uid=blainj
sn=blain

cn=andy-peters,ou=appserver,ou=components,o=hoster
cn=andy
sn=peters
uid=petersa
cn=E09876543
```

**THE OUTPUT I WANT AFTER PROCESSING**

```
joe,bloggs,s01234565;uid=bloggsj,cn=joe-bloggs,ou=appserver,ou=components,o=hoster
john,blain;uid=blainj;cn=john-blain,ou=appserver,ou=components,o=hoster
andy,peters,E09876543;uid=E09876543;cn=andy-peters,ou=appserver,ou=components,o=hoster
```

As you can see:

1. we always have a cn= variable that contains o=hoster
2. uid can have any value
3. we may have multiple cn= variables without o=hoster

I have acheived the following:

```
cat output | awk '!/^o.*/ && !/^Enter.*/{print}' | awk '{getline a; getline b; getline c; getline d;  print  $0,a,b,c,d}' | awk -v srch1="cn=" -v repl1="" -v srch2="sn=" -v repl2="" '{ sub(srch1,repl1,$2); sub(srch2,repl2,$3); print $4";"$2" "$3";"$1 }'
```

Any pointers or guidance is greatly appreciated using awk. Or should I give up and just use the age old long winded method a large looping script to process the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try following ***awk*** code

```
$ cat file
Enter password ==>
o=hoster

ou=people,o=hoster

ou=components,o=hoster

ou=websphere,ou=components,o=hoster

cn=joe-bloggs,ou=appserver,ou=components,o=hoster
cn=joe
sn=bloggs
cn=S01234565
uid=bloggsj

cn=john-blain,ou=appserver,ou=components,o=hoster
cn=john
uid=blainj
sn=blain

cn=andy-peters,ou=appserver,ou=components,o=hoster
cn=andy
sn=peters
uid=petersa
cn=E09876543
```

***Awk Code :***

```
awk      '
   function out(){
                   print s,u,last
                   i=0; s=""
                 }
        /^cn/,!NF{ 
                   ++i      
                   last = i == 1 ? $0 : last
                   s = i>1 && !/uid/ && NF ? s ? s "," $NF : $NF : s
                   u = /uid/ ? $0 : u
                 }
         i && !NF{
                   out()
                 }
              END{
                   out()
                 }
          ' FS="=" OFS=";" file
```

***Resulting***

```
joe,bloggs,S01234565;uid=bloggsj;cn=joe-bloggs,ou=appserver,ou=components,o=hoster
john,blain;uid=blainj;cn=john-blain,ou=appserver,ou=components,o=hoster
andy,peters,E09876543;uid=petersa;cn=andy-peters,ou=appserver,ou=components,o=hoster
```

**If you want to try this on a `Solaris/SunOS` system, change `awk` to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` , `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk`**

Comment: Fantastic and straight forward. I've tried this against a variety of reports and it works perfectly. My awk needs some improving! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` script works for your sample and produces the sample output:

```
BEGIN { delete cn[0]; OFS = ";" }
function print_info() {
    if (length(cn)) {
        names = cn[1] "," sn
        for (i=2; i <= length(cn); ++i) names = names "," cn[i]
        print names, uid, dn
        delete cn
    }
}
/^cn=/ {
    if ($0 ~ /o=hoster/) dn = $0
    else {
        cn[length(cn)+1] = substr($0, index($0, "=") + 1)
        uid = $0; sub("cn", "uid", uid)
    }
}
/^sn=/ { sn = substr($0, index($0, "=") + 1) }
/^uid=/ { uid = $0 }
/^$/ { print_info() }
END { print_info() }
```

This should help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$1 ~ /^cn/ {
  for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
    if ($i ~ /^uid/) {
    u = $i 
    continue
    }
    sub(/^[^=]*=/, x, $i)
    r = length(r) ? r OFS $i : $i
    }
    print r, u, $1 
    r = u = x
  }' OFS=, RS= infile
```

I assume that there is an error in your sample output: in the 3d record the *uid* should be *petersa* and not *E09876543*.

Answer (score 0):

You might want look at some of the "already been there and done that" solutions to accomplish the task.

[Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) for example, will do the LDAP query and save the file in CSV or XLS format.

-jim